# How do I exclude the nodes while plotting an interpolation error?

Tags: python, interpolation

For my studies I am learning python and do have problems with plotting an interpolation error at the nodes.
To be precise I want to exclude the nodes from the `fill_between` function.

I do know:

- The nodes `(-1,-1/2), (1,-1), (3,1/2)`
- *|f'''| <= 10*
- *x* is from *[-2,4]*
- I need to use the *Lagrange remainder formula*
- the interpolation polynomial needs to be a 2nd degree polynomial

For starters here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Intervallgrenzen
a = -2
b = 4

# Input der Datenpunkte
x_list = (-1, 1, 3)
f_list = (-1/2, -1, 1/2)

def divdiff(x_list, f_list):
    # Polynomgrad bestimmen
    p2 = len(x_list) - 1 
    # Nullmatrix F mit p2+1 Spalten und p2+1 Zeilen anlegen
    F = np.zeros((p2+1, p2+1))
    # Erste Spalte von F sind die Funktionswerte
    for j in range(p2+1):
        F[j,0] = f_list[j]
        # Berechnung dividierte Differenzen
        for k in range(1,p2+1):
            for i in range(k,p2+1):
                F[i,k] = (F[i,k-1] - F[i-1,k-1])/(x_list[i] - x_list[i-k])
    # Diagonalwerte reichen aus
    return(np.diag(F))

N = 100
X = np.linspace(-2, 4, N)
A = divdiff(x_list, f_list)
# Überprüfung der Koeffizienten
print(A)

# Berechnung des Interpolationspolynoms
P = A[0] + A[1]*(X - x_list[0]) + A[2]*((X - x_list[0])*(X - x_list[1]))

# intervallweise Fehlerabschätzung mit |f'''| <= 10
# In der Nähe der Datenpunkten funktioniert es nicht wie gewollt. Ist die Fehlerabschätzung korrekt?
X1 = np.linspace(-1, 3, N)
R1o = abs((1/6)*10*(X1 - x_list[0])*(X1 - x_list[1])*(X1 - x_list[2]))
R1u = -abs((1/6)*10*(X1 - x_list[0])*(X1 - x_list[1])*(X1 - x_list[2]))

X3 = np.linspace(-2, -1, N)
R3o = abs((1/6)*10*(X3 - x_list[0])*(X3 - x_list[1])*(X3 - x_list[2]))
R3u = -abs((1/6)*10*(X3 - x_list[0])*(X3 - x_list[1])*(X3 - x_list[2]))

X4 = np.linspace(3, 4, N)
R4o = abs((1/6)*10*(X4 - x_list[0])*(X4- x_list[1])*(X4 - x_list[2]))
R4u = -abs((1/6)*10*(X4 - x_list[0])*(X4 - x_list[1])*(X4 - x_list[2]))

plt.title("Serie 7, Aufgabe 4")
plt.ylim([-20,20])
plt.plot(X,P,color='k',label='$p_2(x)$')
plt.scatter(x_list,f_list,color='y',marker='o',label='$Datenpunkte$')
plt.fill_between(X1, R1o, R1u, color="cyan", label='$Interpolation$')
plt.fill_between(X3, R3o, R3u, color="red", label='$Extrapolation$')
plt.fill_between(X4, R4o, R4u, color="red")
plt.legend(loc='upper center')
plt.savefig("Interpolation mit Fehlerabschätzung")
plt.show()
```

My comments are in German so feel free to ask me to clarify if needed.

Here's my plot:
[image]

And here's how the plot should look:
[image]

I am aware my remainder polynomial takes the value of *0* for *x = -1, 1, 3*.

So I tried:

```py
X1 = np.linspace(-1, 3, N)

for l in range(0,3):
   if X1.any() == x_list[l]:
      R1o = f_list[l]
      R1u = f_list[l]
else:
   R1o = abs((1/6)*10*(X1 - x_list[0])*(X1 - x_list[1])*(X1 - x_list[2]))
   R1u = -abs((1/6)*10*(X1 - x_list[0])*(X1 - x_list[1])*(X1 - x_list[2]))
```

With that I am just plotting a linear function so I concluded I just did *R1o = R1u* with that code.

Any help is much appreciated.